# Ruby: how to repeat/multiply elements in array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Let's say I have an array:

```
array = ["A", "B", "C"]
```

...and I need to repeat each element 5 times, to get this:

```
array2 = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"]
```

Here is the code I use:

```
arr = ["A", "B", "C"] 
arr2 = [] 
arr.each do |a| 
  5.times do 
    arr2.push(a) 
  end 
end
```

But I was just curious, is there a way to do the same thing **in one line of code**?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve]. [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me-service"! If you are looking for *that*, hire a programmer.

Comment: "How to solve it in one line of code?" – You solve it by writing a line of code that does what you want. If you have trouble with your code, you research the problems, debug your code, write test cases, single-step the execution, trace the flow of control and data on a piece of paper, sleep on it, try again on the next day, and then and *only then* if you still can't figure it out, you ask a focused, complete, narrow question on [so].

Comment: @JörgWMittag - I've answered you by editing my question.

Comment: Are the elements in the `array` unique?

Comment: "But I was just curious, how to solve it in one line of code." – Linebreaks are optional in Ruby (although sometimes they need to be replaced with something else like a keyword or a semicolon), so any problem can be solved in one line of code just by removing the linebreaks: `arr = ["A", "B", "C"]; arr2 = []; arr.each do |a| 5.times do arr2.push(a) end end`. Since *everything* can be trivially written in one line by just removing the linebreaks, the question "how to solve it in one line code of code" isn't terribly interesting.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - really? This is not what I was asking for, and you know that. Your malice is useless.

Comment: It seems that you have found a bug in [so]. I think it would be a good idea to report it on [meta]. The [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44757202/revisions) says that the sentence "How to solve it in one line of code?" as well as the sentence "But I was just curious, how to solve it in one line of code." were added by you, but you say that that's not what you wrote, correct?

Comment: " you say that that's not what you wrote" - I don't say this, I say this is not what I am asking for. Sorry, I am not going to continue this worthless discussion anymore.

Comment: @JörgWMittag seems to be having a bad day and a lot of spare time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one

```
array.flat_map { |item| Array.new(5, item) }
[
    [ 0] "A",
    [ 1] "A",
    [ 2] "A",
    [ 3] "A",
    [ 4] "A",
    [ 5] "B",
    [ 6] "B",
    [ 7] "B",
    [ 8] "B",
    [ 9] "B",
    [10] "C",
    [11] "C",
    [12] "C",
    [13] "C",
    [14] "C"
]
```

Comment: `Array.new(5, item)`

Comment: Thanks, you're right :)

Comment: why this new version is better than the previous one (which also works for me)? I mean this: flat_map { |item| Array(item) * 5 }

Comment: @msayen, it works faster and consumes less memory.

Comment: True, cool even that :)

Comment: Alternatively, `array.flat_map { |item| [item]*5 }`.

Comment: Yep, thanks Cary, but that was my first answer :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution that has the drawback of hardcoding the number of repetitions:

```
array.zip(array, array, array, array).flatten
```

#### Update

As @knut suggests (thank you!), it can be made dynamic by using the [asterisk operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion):

```
array.zip(*[array]*4).flatten
```

It looks nice and it works but, all in all, I think [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44757231/4265352) provided by @Ursus works faster and uses less memory than any solution that uses [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-zip), no matter how its list of arguments is generated.

Comment: You could make it more dynamic with the asterisk operator:  `array.zip(*[array]*4).flatten`

Comment: ... or `array.zip(*Array.new(4,array)).flatten`

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
(arr*5).sort_by { |i| arr.index(i) }
#=> ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
#    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
#    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"]
```

<sup>Caveat: Assumes `arr.uniq == arr`.</sup>

Comment: Won't work for `["A", "B", "A"]`

Comment: @Stefan okay I've added a caveat.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a nested loop. One that takes A, B, C, D, and E one after the other and the in loop which will appends the new array with 5 times iteration(preferably a for loop iteration) on that same alphabet. I think this should work and should save you more time and code lines and runtime.

Question: (Rhetorical though) If you want to do the same for alphabets from A-Z would you input the elements manually?

Answer (score 0):

Another one-liner, just for fun:

```
([array] * 5).transpose.flatten
=> ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"]
```